# sentry 2 cartalyst permission package use in php

Tags: php, cartalyst-sentry

when  try to install sentry 2 with composer it will installed very well. but how can  use in existing PHP project thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all I would advise you to switch to Sentinel 2 from Sentry
  as Sentry is deprecated now.
- Now for using it in your existing project you need to replace the existing Authentication system with that of Senty's. For that you will have to replace all the -

  - Sign Up
  - Sign In
  - Sign Out and
  - Authentication middleware

methods with that of sentry's.

It would be good if you follow the Sentinel documentaion. It's a good one for beginners.
[Sentinel 2.0](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0)

Also a lot depends on the PHP framework you are using for your backend. If you are using something big like zend, yii etc. they already have a pretty good authentication system of their own.

If you are using a light weight framework suppose Slim then there the documentation will guide you pretty well to set it up. Also there are various blogs online explaining the same.